# Search trajectory point close to line

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

There is a 2d mechanism:

[image: 2d mechanism]

Link AB can be rigidly tied to a point at a distance less than the radius of the circle R0 with center B to show the trajectories:

[image: 2d mechanism with a circle]

If 4 random points are rigidly tied to the AB link and the trajectories are constructed from 30 positions, then it can be seen that parts of some trajectories describe a close trajectory.

[image: Animation]

[image: 2d mechanism]

---

Question:

1) quality test.

How do you know that there is a point inside the circle R0 that can describe parts of a trajectory close to a straight line?

2) quantitative test.

How to find out where the point is located; the part of the trajectory of which is closest to the straight line in Fig. "perfect straight"?

This mechanism, for example, will be different. In fact, the mechanism can be viewed as a function that takes an angle from 0 to 2pi and returns two vectors A and B defining the position of the segment AB in 2d. The number of trajectory points is any, but preferably a minimum for calculation.

How to solve this problem in the forehead?

1) take for example 1000 points inside R0

2) we find 1000 trajectories from for example 30 points each

3) we are looking for a close to straight section on the 
broken line (if there is one at all)

4) we consider the sum of the deviations of points from the line

5) find which of the 1000 trajectories there is a minimum of deviation

6) in the vicinity of the solution again for example 100 points in a smaller radius and again search ...

This is a lot of calculations, this analysis is part of the brutofors (brute force).
 It is necessary with a minimum of calculations to look for close to straight broken.

---

**Edit:** The essence of the task is as simple as possible.

I guess I painted the mechanism for nothing, maybe it only distracts and confuses.

Imagine a sheet of paper on a table with two points A and B and C rigidly attached to the sheet.

[image: pic 1]

Set the sheet N positions through the coordinates A and B moving the sheet in the plane of the table.

[image: pic 2]

How to find such a point C on a sheet, the part of the trajectory of which (if constructed, the red one in the figure) draws the trajectory closest to the straight (blue straight line).

[image: pic 3]

Initially, the options for the position of C inside the sheet are infinite, taking random 1000 points is a lot of calculations. How is it even possible to find such a point C?
After all, this is one rigid body whose orientation is given, why should he count 1000 trajectories of points and look in them?

Or is the solution of the problem even approximately analytically impossible? At least the area where it seems that point C describes a part of its trajectory close to the line.
Can decompose N positions into two graphs, one shift of the body of the second bite?
Perhaps this is differential geometry or mathematical analysis ... I do not know. There are so many sections of mathematics, such complex tasks are solved here, and no one solves such a seemingly simple task ... Already 4 forums in mathematics have no solutions = (.

Comment: Can  you change "differential geometry" and "mathematical analysis" and remove "classical mechanics" tag?
And how to show pictures and not links?

Comment: I believe you can accept and/or modify/reject my edits. Pictures can be shown, if you have sufficient rep, by just adding an exclamation mark `!` at the start.